# order by most recent element of another table (django queryset)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a Users table and a Scores table. Each score has a created_at timestamp and is associated with a user; a user may have multiple scores. They are unique on user and created_at. How do I return the users whose most recent scores are the 5 lowest? I know how to do this in raw sql, not sure how to do this in queryset. Here is my attempt:

```
from .models import User
users = User.objects.all().order_by('score__score')[:5]
```

However this just sorts by the users with lowest all time scores - I want to only use the most recently created score for each user. In SQL, the code would be

```
SELECT u.user, t.score FROM
users u JOIN
(SELECT s.user, s.score FROM
 scores s JOIN
 (SELECT user, max(created_at) created_at FROM
  scores 
  GROUP BY user) c
 ON s.user = c.user AND s.created_at = c.created_at
) t
ON u.user = t.user
ORDER BY score
LIMIT 5
```

Edit: added models

```
class User(models.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)                                                      
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                                        
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                                            
    def __unicode__(self):                                                                      
        return self.name                                                                        

class Score(models.Model):                                                                                                                                                       
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)                                                       
    score = models.FloatField()                                                                 
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                                        
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                                            
    def __unicode__(self):                                                                      
        return str(self.score)
```

Comment: Can you try`Score.objects.values('user', 'score').annotate(latest_date=Max('created_at')).order_by('score')`? Also remember `from django.db.models.aggregates import Max`

Comment: How about `User.objects.values('id', 'score__score').annotate(latest_date=Max('score__created_at')).order_by('score__score')[:5]`?